# SlideJS change width

Tags: jquery, width

I am looking for a way to change the SlideJS width. I would like to have it all 950px with the  arrows included. Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just set size of your container and position the arrows using CSS. Here's an example of a code I used: http://jsfiddle.net/planxdesign/LpPTY/